# Hibernate ClassCastException while comparing int and long

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hql

I have a HQLquery file that contains around 800 queries. Query to be executed in detected at run time and arguements passed from browser are mapped, by default my code converts argument passed from browser  to Long.The problem is in some bean classes the variable(i.e Left side of comparision) is int and in some case it is Long. But at run time I am not able to think of any way to detect the "type" of Left side of comparison argument.

say : select * from employee e where e.id=$empid$

$empid$ is replaced with the value passed from browser at run time and by default my code cast the passed value to Long.  If e.id is int then this will throw ClassCastException . Is there is any way to detect type of e.id at run time. Or any other idea to solve this problem.

I tried casting RHS to Number but it dint work for me. Any suggestion will be very much appriciated. Thanks

Comment: Check EmployeeEntity's ID field's class whether it's Integer or Long

Comment: Our hql queries are defined as key value pairs in a properties file. The key is passed as input and the value is the actual HQL query in string format.

Input to the function is (NamedQueryKey, ParameterList)
We do not know at runtime what are the Beans involved in the query passed in NamedQueryKey unless we parse the query( which we want to avoid)

Comment: Then rewrite all entities to use Long as id column type

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to access the ClassMetadata:

```
ClassMetadata metadata=sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(Employee.class);
```

You write your HQL query as follows:

```
Number id = ...;
Type identifierType = metadata.getIdentifierType();
Class identifierClass = identifierType.getReturnedClass();                                

if(Long.class.equals(identifierClass)) {
    id = id.longValue();
} else {
    id = id.intValue();
}

session.createQuery("select e from Employee e where e.id = :id")
   .setParameter("id", id, identifierType)
   .list();
```

Supplying the actual type should fix your issue.